Question 7 from A first course in Probability by Sheldon Ross 10 ed. chapter 2.

A bus departs from Bus Stop 16 with 20 passengers. The bus's journey will end at Bus Stop 20. Passengers can leave the bus at any stop, but no passengers can board. Work out the number of possibilities in:
(a) the whole sample space
(b) the event that no passenger leaves at Bus Stops 16 or 18.
(c) the event that half of the passengers leave by Bus Stop 18.

The solution I tried for question (a) For stop 17 every passenger had $2^{20}$ choices.
For stop 18 every passenger had
$
^{20}C_02^{20}+ ^{20}C_12^{19}+ ^{20}C_22^{18}+....+^{20}C_{20}2^{20}
$ choices. 
For stop 19 every passenger had
$
^{20}C_02^{20}+ ^{20}C_12^{19}+ ^{20}C_22^{18}+....+^{20}C_{20}2^{20}
$ choices. 
For stop 20 every passenger had only 1 choce to leave.
There is no answer in the book so i am confused that am I right or not.

Either I don’t understand the question, or the answer for (a) is just $4^{20}$, because each of $20$ passengers can leave at any of the $4$ stops: $17,18,19,20$?

A much simpler way to enumerate the sample space is to label each passenger, say $$P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_{20}$$
and for each $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 20\}$, passenger $P_i$ must disembark from the bus at exactly one of the stops $\{17, 18, 19, 20\}$.  This admits $4$ distinct choices for each passenger, and because the passengers are distinct, there must be $4^{20}$ unique ways for the passengers to disembark from the bus.  You can see how your initial reasoning was getting close to the answer, but by splitting the outcomes by the stop number, you unnecessarily complicated the counting process.
To answer (a) completely, we need to specify the sample space of elementary outcomes:  This may be accomplished by using the aforementioned labeling of each passenger as positions in a vector of length $20$, and the value in position $i$ corresponds to the stop at which the $i^{\rm th}$ passenger disembarked:
$$\mathcal S = \{(P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_{20}) : P_i \in \{17, 18, 19, 20\}\}.$$  A more compact way to write this is $$\mathcal S = \{17, 18, 19, 20\}^{20};$$ i.e., all ordered $20$-tuples of the set $\{17, 18, 19, 20\}$.  For instance, one element of $\mathcal S$ might be
$$(17, 20, 18, 18, 20, 19, 19, 17, 20, 20, 18, 17, 20, 20, 17, 19, 18, 20, 17, 17).$$
As for part (b) of the question, the reasoning applied in (a) can be reused.  The details are left as an exercise.
For part (c), it is unclear whether by "half" the author means exactly half, or at least half.  I will assume the former.  Then the counting of the number of such outcomes may be accomplished through a two-stage process.  We would first split the passengers into two cohorts of equal size of $10$ each.  In one cohort, the last passenger to depart in that cohort does so before stop $19$.  In the second cohort, the first passenger to depart in that cohort does so after stop $18$.  We would count the number of ways to assign a cohort to each passenger, then count the number of ways for each cohort's passengers to be assigned stop numbers.  Again, the details are left as an exercise.

I've also faced problems with this question and the most reasonable answer that I was able to think of was using the standard 'stars and bars problem'.
(a) So, the sample space can be defined as, S = {($x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$): such that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20$, where $x_i \ge 0$ means the number of passengers leaving at Bus stop 16, 17, 18, 19 or 20 when i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Hence, clearly the number of possible outcomes in the sample space will be,
\begin{align*}
&\\ \binom{n+r-1}{r-1} => \binom{20+5-1}{5-1} = \binom{24}{4} = 10626\end{align*}
In this manner,
(b) the event that no passenger leaves at Bus Stops 16 or 18 means fixing $x_1$ = 0 or $x_3$ = 0 in the sample space.
(c) the event that half of the passengers leave by Bus Stop 18 means fixing $x_3$ = 10 in the sample space.
And by this the number of possible outcomes in (b) and (c) can be found out easily.

Part (a) is wrong; see the comment of AIG, immediately following the posted question.  The reason that (in general) Stars and Bars is the wrong approach here is that (for example) in the specific case of $~x_1 = a,~$ no distinction is made for which of the people represent the $~a~$ people assigned to the variable $~x_1.~$ If you re-read the posted question, and then read AIG's comment, I believe that you will find that his comment makes sense.
